Generated Plugins and MainActivity error in flutter
Can someone tell me why this whole code is causing errors?

The import statements are giving errors with, Keep, NonNull, Log, and embedding words
The getPlugins() method is throwing error
Other words, like firebase, dextorous, googlesignin, dev, baseflow, tekartik are causing errors

All the errors have the same cause.
That is cannot resolve this?
    package io.flutter.plugins;
    
    import androidx.annotation.Keep;
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import io.flutter.Log;
    
    import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
    
    /**
     * Generated file. Do not edit.
     * This file is generated by the Flutter tool based on the
     * plugins that support the Android platform.
     */
    @Keep
    public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
      private static final String TAG = "GeneratedPluginRegistrant";
      public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        try {
          flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin firebase_auth, io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth.FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin", e);
        }
        try {
          flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin firebase_core, io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin", e);
        }
        try {
          flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin flutter_local_notifications, com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin", e);
        }
        try {
          flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin google_sign_in_android, io.flutter.plugins.googlesignin.GoogleSignInPlugin", e);
        }
        try {
          flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new dev.flutter.plugins.integration_test.IntegrationTestPlugin());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin integration_test, dev.flutter.plugins.integration_test.IntegrationTestPlugin", e);
        }
        try {
          flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.baseflow.permissionhandler.PermissionHandlerPlugin());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin permission_handler_android, com.baseflow.permissionhandler.PermissionHandlerPlugin", e);
        }
        try {
          flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin());
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin sqflite, com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin", e);
        }
      }
    }

MainActivity.kt:
    package com.example.habit_maker

    import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

    class MainActivity: FlutterActivity()

In this kotlin file the embedding word is giving the same error that is cannot resolve?
This is my first app and I don't know anything, what to do in that situation?
